# Linux command line....How do I change from $ to #?

Tags: linux, command-line, fedora

I'm working with the sed editor and I realize that my command prompt is:

[darkchild@localhost ~]$

How can I change this so that it ends in #....and what does this mean?
for example:

[darkchild@localhost ~]#

A friend told me to write this command #!/bin/bash but it does not change the prompt to #.

Can someone educate me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Canonically # means root shell.  You probably do not actually want to do this, because it would confuse other users of your system.  If you do actually want to do this, you can edit the PROMPT variable.

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/

Comment: does it make an actual difference? will i be interacting with the machine or shell differently?

Comment: No actual difference. The user will see something that says "I'm root" but their permissions will still be their own.

Comment: +1 Good answer! (and more explanatory & detailed then mine)

Answer (score 1):

You can run the following command:

```
set prompt=\[`id -nu`@`hostname -s`\]\#\
```

Comment: does it make an actual difference? will i be interacting with the machine or shell differently?

Comment: Nope. This is a "display only" thing. You can't acquire `root` privileges by changing the display of prompt

Comment: @JustinChiang you can accept only one answer :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the root user. You can go to this user using the `su` command.
More info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Su_(Unix)